# Docker error when running container Error: Cannot find module '/home/app/server.js'

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm getting the following error and I'm struggling to find the issue

After successfully building my image using the following Dockerfile
Command used

> docker build -t my-app:1.0 .

```
FROM node:13-alpine

# run something in the docker image
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# this allows you to copy something from the host into docker image
COPY . /home/app

# inside the container it runs the command node server.js
# cmd is an entry point command, whereas run as used later
CMD ["node","/home/app/server.js"]
```

I have run the following command to run the container

> docker run my-app:1.0

it throws the following error:

```
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
192:docker_compose_demo tech$ docker run my-app:1.0
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/app/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I changed the path in the Dockerfile and yet is not finding it.
Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Run `docker run my-app:1.0 ls -al /home/app` to see the contents of the /home/app directory in the image and check if server.js is there.

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @HansKilian when I run that, I don't see any server.js file there. I'm using the node official image, it should have one right?

Comment: It'll only have one if you copy one into the image with your COPY statement.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is, to use the `WORKDIR` instead of running `mkdir`.
Why use `WORKDIR` ?

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD,
> ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the
> Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if
> it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction

You can refer the below Dockerfile -

```
FROM node:13-alpine

# Creates directory and sets it as current working directory
WORKDIR /home/app

# Copy everything from local current directory to docker/image current directory
COPY . .

# inside the container it runs the command node server.js
# cmd is an entry point command, whereas run as used later
CMD ["node","server.js"]
```

Comment: I have tried this but I'm getting the same error

Comment: do you have the ```server.js``` file available in the directory where your ```Dockerfile``` is?

Comment: I don't have it, i suspect this comes with the image, the guide I followed never mentioned putting a server.js file in the directory

Comment: Looks like you haven't done proper research with regards to NodeJs. ```server.js``` file or ```anyfile.js``` never comes in built with the node docker image, it is something that you need to write. It will contain your business logic.